# VBA Error code "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure"

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that I copied from somewhere else.

The code is not working and gives me an error.

Can someone please review and advise if there is a syntax error

```
Dim directory As String, filename As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "U:\GMR & PAYROLL REPORTS 2018-19\FEBRUARY 2019\COMPLETED\PAYSLIPS\"
filename = Dir(directory & "*.csv")

Do While filename <> " "
    Workbooks.Open (directory & filename)
        WrdArray() = Split(filename, ".")
        For Each sheet In Workbooks(filename).Worksheets
            Wookbooks(filename).ActiveSheet.Name = WrdArray(0)
            total = Workbooks("PAYSLIPS CONSOL.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
            Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy after:=Workbooks("PAYSLIPS CONSOL.xlxm").Worksheets(total)

            GoTo exitFor:

        Next sheet

exitFor:
    Workbooks(filename).Close
    filename = Dir()
Loop
Sheets("ALL HOMES").Select
lastsheets = Worksheets.Count
For i = 2 To lastsheets
mysheet = Sheets(i).Activate
mysheetrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Range("A1;U" & mysheetrow).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("ALL HOMES").Select
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1Up).Row
Range("A1").Select
Range("A" & lastrow).Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
MsgBox "Your Report is Ready"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you googled to see what causes this error? Perhaps you don't have a Sub line at the top.

Comment: Also, your constant should be `xlUp` and not `x1Up`

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can use VBA compiler to check whether your project can compile. To do this in the VBA Editor, click Debug -> Compile VBA Project. Everytime you click it, it will either run smoothly and say nothing, or show you the first compilation error in the project it runs into (so you can fix it and click Compile again).

I tried to compile the code you posted:

First, as suggested in the comment, you don't have the Sub line at the top. For example

```
Sub create_payroll()
```

, where create_payroll is your preferred name for this macro. Put this line right above all the code you posted in the question.

Second, there is a typo "Wookbooks" instead of Workbooks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am now getting error - "Run-time error '9':  Subscript out of range"

Comment: Can you specify which line throws an error? To find out, you can use Debug options, e.g. by pressing F8 in VBA Editor.